# @ElementCollection to contain at least one element and at most N elements

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

is there a way to apply reference count constraint for entity referenced by `@ElementCollection`?

Simplified example:

```
public enum Key {
    A, S, D;
};

@Entity
public class Keyboard {
     @Id
     Long id;

     // require at least one key?
     // require at most N keys?
     @ElementCollection(targetClass = Key.class)
     @JoinTable(name = "keyboard_key", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "keyboard_id"))
     @Column(name = "key", nullable = false)
     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     Set<Key> keys; 
}
```

`Keyboard` must have at least `1` `Key`. Also it would be nice to have at most `N` `Key`s.

Considering `KeyboardRepository`:

```
public interface KeyboardRepository extends JpaRepository<Keyboard, Long> {}

//...
@Autowired
KeyboardRepository repo;

//..
repo.save(new Keyboard(/*id*/null, /*keys*/null); // should throw due to no-keys
repo.save(new Keyboard(/*id*/null, /*keys*/Sets.newSet()); // should throw due to no-keys
repo.save(new Keyboard(/*id*/null, /*keys*/Sets.newSet(Key.A, Key.S, Key.D)); // should throw due to eg. at most 2 keys
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `javax.validation.constraints.Size` annoatione like this:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Key.class)
     @JoinTable(name = "keyboard_key", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "keyboard_id"))
     @Column(name = "key", nullable = false)
     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     @Size(min = 1, max = N)
     Set<Key> keys;
```

For more details check out how to use java bean validation in spring-boot https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation